# Count div by div and show number per div, not total numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I only found lots of answers to show the total number of some special divs, like this way:

```
$('.someclass').length
```

... but my problem is, that I want to count div by div with a numerical sequence.

For example, I have the following list ...

```
<ul>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
</ul>
```

... now I want to count every li element and add automatically a number from low to high, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Some content <span class="number">1</span></li>
  <li>Some content <span class="number">2</span></li>
  <li>Some content <span class="number">3</span></li>
</ul>
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul li').each(function(i) {
    var self = $(this);
    self.html(self.html() + ' <span class="number">' + (i+1) + '</span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Pepe don't forget to mark the question if that solve your problem.

Comment: I cant .. I have to wait 8 minutes, sry ;(

Answer (score 1):

You could use the index:

```js
$('ul li').append(function() {
  return ' <span>' + ($(this).index() + 1) + '</span>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having your HTML like this:

```
<ul class="someClass">
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
</ul>
```

Then to do what you're trying to do in JQuery:

```
var count = 0;
$('.someClass li').each(function(){
    count++;
    $(this).append('<span class="number">'+count+'</span>');
});
```

Comment: jcubics answer already works for me, but also thx for support!